# How to make works ACF Gutenberg Block for Post Type - Post?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have registered Gutenberg Block by the way

```
add_action( 'acf/init', 'acf__init__register_acf_block_types' );
function acf__init__register_acf_block_types() {
    acf_register_block_type(
        [
            'name'            => 'my-block',
            'title'           => Translator::_x( 'My Block', 'Gutenberg Blocks Names' ),
            'description'     => Translator::_x( 'My Block', 'Gutenberg Blocks Description' ),
            'render_template' => 'components/my-block/template/acf-block.php',
            'category'        => 'my-blocks',
            'icon'            => 'admin-home',
            'keywords'        => [ 'my-block', 'builder', 'block' ],
            'enqueue_assets'  => function () {
                $my_block = new My_Block();
                $my_block->wp_enqueue_scripts();
            },
        ]
    );
}
```

For **Post type** `Page` this block works.

For **Post type** - `Post` - the block is being shown for admin menu.
But is commented out for Frontend.

Comment: Try to pass 'post_types' => array('post', 'page'), parameter and check

Comment: @BrijeshDhanani, its default params. I've tried. Not solve the problem.